# "Aber zur Zeit sie ist die Hausfrau " instead of "Aber zur Zeit ist sie Hausfrau" -position of 'sie'

Tags: grammaticality

I am new to German so would be grateful if someone could help with this trivial question.

When doing some exercises from my course book I saw such an example

> Aber zur Zeit ist sie Hausfrau.

The question is the **position of the subject**. What if I change the sentence into "Aber zur Zeit sie ist die Hausfrau" or "Aber sie ist Hausfrau zur Zeit"

Comment: `Aber zur Zeit ist sie die Hausfrau` would point out that there is a role called `Hausfrau` which is taken by one of a group that is responsible to fill that position. And this one female (`sie`) is currently taking that role. Just as another  word order adjacent to your examples with different meaning. Same would be `Aber zur Zeit ist sie die Chefin` - there is a boss and more than one person is eligible to be boss.

Answer (score 9):

Let's take a look at the **valid** example you gave as well as the other valid permutations:

> Aber sie **ist** zur Zeit Hausfrau.
>
> Aber Hausfrau **ist** sie zur Zeit.
>
> Aber Hausfrau **ist** zur Zeit sie.
>
> Aber zur Zeit **ist** sie Hausfrau.

These are all valid. The difference is in the emphasis. The item in front of the finite verb gets the most emphasis, it's the topic. The item at the end of the sentence gets the second most emphasis.

The iron rule of building declarative clause in German is the **V2 rule**. The finite verb comes second. Or, to put it differently.

- In declarative clauses, there is **exactly one item** in front of the finite verb.

Not one word, but one item. For example the subject, an object, an adverbial, including all the articles, pronoun, counter belonging to it. It may also be a whole clause. But only one.

Your example features an exception though. **Aber** is a so called *0th item*, which does not count. These are mostly interjections and particles.

Now you can tell why

> <s>Aber zur Zeit sie **ist** die Hausfrau.</s>

is invalid.

---

In case you wonder there are two more permutations which should be valid according to the above rule. But they aren't for complicated reasons.

> Aber sie **ist** Hausfrau zur Zeit. *(at least uncommon with  an adverbial of time)*
>
> Aber zur Zeit **ist** Hausfrau sie. *(uncommon apart from poetry)*

Answer (score 4):

"Aber zur Zeit sie ist die Hausfrau" would be incorrect. Since you are starting the sentence using a temporal adverb ("Zur Zeit") the verb ("ist") has to follow --> Aber zur Zeit ist sie Hausfrau.

You can change it to "Aber sie ist Hausfrau zur Zeit", that is correct :)

Comment: Hi Victoria, welcome to German StackExchange and thank you for your answer! Please note that you shouldn’t write greetings (“bye” etc.) or sign your posts with your name here. Please take a minute to familiarize yourself with the way this community works in the [help center](https://german.stackexchange.com/help).